Condition for an elliptic integral to be solvable
When we are faced with integrals like this, how would one know if the integral is solvable or unsolvable
$$f(x) = \int \sqrt{ P(t)} \,dt$$
By solvable I mean the integral can be broken down into an elementary function, and by unsolvable I mean the integral cannot be broken that to an elementary function “ Elliptic integral “ when the $P$ is a polynomial of degree $3$ or $4$
All elliptic integrals can be written in terms of three standard types: first, second and third
$$F(x ; k) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{\left(1 - t^2\right)\left(1 - k^2 t^2\right)}}$$
$$E(x;k) = \int_0^x \frac{\sqrt{1-k^2 t^2} }{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt$$
$$\Pi(n ; \varphi \,|\,m) = \int_{0}^{\sin \varphi} \frac{1}{1-nt^2} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{\left(1-m t^2\right)\left(1-t^2\right) }}$$
Question: let $A$ and $B$ be polynomials of degree $2$,$3$ or $4$, without attempting to solve the integral, what is the condition that determines if the integral is elliptic or not
$$f(x) = \int \sqrt{\frac{A(t)}{B(t)}} \,dt$$

The term you are looking for is "closed form" no?

Possibly this is dealt with in one or more of the references in my answer(s) to this MSE question or in Hardy's Integration of Functions of a Single Variable (search in-page for "Hardy" in my previously cited MSE answer for a copy of the book and where to look).
